# Throws ClassCastException while navigating through the popup menu with the arrow keys

Tags: java, classcastexception

I have a menuBar that contains JMenu's and JMenuItem's. If i navigate with my arrow keys, the program throws a ClassCastException as soon as you encounter a JMenuItem.
Is there a way to catch this exception or make sure that you skip the JMenuItem's while navigating?

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

  public GUI() {
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();

    JMenu firstButtonMenu = new JMenu("Button 1");
    firstButtonMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Sub 1"));
    firstButtonMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Sub 2"));

    JMenu secondButtonMenu = new JMenu("Button 2");
    secondButtonMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Sub 1"));
    secondButtonMenu.add(new JMenuItem("Sub 2"));

    menuBar.add(firstButtonMenu);
    menuBar.add(secondButtonMenu);
    menuBar.add(new JMenuItem("Button 3"));

    add(menuBar);
    setVisible(true);
    pack();

  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of trying to catch the exception to work around the problem, it would be much better to fix the bug in your code that causes the exception.

Comment: If you don't get a fast answer, it would be helpful to flesh out the code so it is a fully compileable example we can copy and paste in our IDE immediately--that helps folks help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only add `JMenu` objects to a `JMenuBar`, not `JMenuItem` objects.

If you don't, you will get :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.JMenuItem cannot be cast to javax.swing.JMenu
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPopupMenuUI$Actions.selectParentChild(BasicPopupMenuUI.java:531)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPopupMenuUI$Actions.actionPerformed(BasicPopupMenuUI.java:426)
```

`JMenuBar` has a `add(JMenu)` method that you are already using .

But if you are passing a `JMenuItem`, this method won't be called, but the inherited `add(Component)` from `java.awt.Container` will be instead, that's why you *can* add any `Component` though only `JMenuItem` is correctly supported.

The underlying BasicPopupMenuUI class (see line 531 : [BasicPopupMenuUI.java](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicPopupMenuUI.java)), expects all the components added to a menu bar to be `JMenu` objects, to the point that a forced cast is done in the code, and that's where the crash occurs :

`newSelection[2] = ((JMenu)nextMenu).getPopupMenu();`

So just add your component as a menu :

```
menuBar.add(new JMenu("Button 3"));
```

Also don't use `add` for a menu bar, consider using `setJMenuBar(menuBar)` instead .